# Compostion with javascript - no inheritance

Tags: javascript

I try to use the speak method also to re use with the Zebra class with composition.

SO I have it like this:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  speak() {
    return `my name is: ${this.name} and I am ${this.age} old`;
  }
}

class Zebra {
  constructor(Animal) {
    this.animal = Animal();
  }
}

let animal = new Animal("hello", 99);
let zebra = new Zebra();

console.log(zebra.speak());
```

also composition!!:

```
class Person {
   String Title;
   String Name;
   Int Age;

   public Person(String title, String name, String age) {
      this.Title = title;
      this.Name = name;
      this.Age = age;
   }

}

class Employee {
   Int Salary;
   private Person person;

   public Employee(Person p, Int salary) {
       this.person = p;
       this.Salary = salary;
   }
}

Person johnny = new Person ("Mr.", "John", 25);
Employee john = new Employee (johnny, 50000);
```

Comment: annnnd what is the problem?

Comment: This isn't an appropriate use for composition. Composition represents the HAS-A relationship, but Zebra IS-A Animal. You should use inheritance for this.

Comment: You have problems with your code
`this.animal = Animal();` - that throws an error, also, you didn't pass any arguments to `new Zebra()` but you expect one in the constructor

Comment: @mightycodeNewton: *"I have learned never use Inheritance."* - You have learned incorrectly.  *"So it is possible to do this with composition."* - That statement is correct.  Now, what specific problem are you observing in your code?  The code shown is producing an error.  Are you asking about that specific error?  What is your question about that specific error?

Comment: You are getting downvotes because your code doesn't even compile, you are making incorrect statements and you insist that everyone except you is wrong.

Comment: If you correct your code you'll isolate the actual problems it suffers rather than just the errors based on typos/syntax

Comment: `also composition!!:` @mightycodeNewton ok composition. What's the value of `john.Name`? not `johnny.Name`, the `Employee` name. Where's that property? If you've found it, look right next to it and you'll find the method `zebra.speak`.

Comment: besides, check out the concept of [tag:mixins]. I think that pattern might fit better what you seem to try to do in your code than composition.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton could you provide a source which claims that using inheritance is bad?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski All the bad practice blogs have such posts :-D GeeksForGeeks, Medium. dev.to, ... e.g. https://codeburst.io/inheritance-is-evil-stop-using-it-6c4f1caf5117

Comment: _"Prefer composition over inheritance"_ and _"Never use inheritance"_ are two different statements. The upvoted answers has examples and use-cases for inheritance.

Comment: That's the strategy pattern. It uses inheritance. A human has-a speak strategy. The human speak strategy inherits from the abstract speak strategy.

Comment: Your other question is for Python. There are no interfaces. You use inheritance. JavaScript doesn't have interfaces, too. It's also inheritance. It's a big difference whether you implement an is-a relationship in terms of composition or in terms of strategies. It's nonsense to implement a zebra in terms of has-an animal. But you could implement it in terms of has animal behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend to use composition in this case. This is a use-case for inheritance. But academic questions also deserve an answer.

Either use the `animal` property to call `speak`:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  speak() {
    return `my name is: ${this.name} and I am ${this.age} old`;
  }
}

class Zebra {
  constructor(animal) {
    this.animal = animal;
  }
}

let animal = new Animal("hello", 99);
let zebra = new Zebra(animal);

console.log(zebra.animal.speak());
```

or add a `speak` method to `Zebra` (this is a duplicate of another answer by accident. I didn't see it because it doesn't contain a runnable snippet):

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  speak() {
    return `my name is: ${this.name} and I am ${this.age} old`;
  }
}

class Zebra {
  constructor(animal) {
    this.animal = animal;
  }

  speak() {
    return this.animal.speak();
  }
}

let animal = new Animal("hello", 99);
let zebra = new Zebra(animal);

console.log(zebra.speak());
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be more of a thing you are looking for

```js
const animal = {
  age: 10,
  name: 'hello',
  speak() {
    return `my name is: ${this.name} and I am ${this.age} old`
  }
}

const zebra = {
  ...animal,
  age: 100,
  name: 'zebra'
}

console.log(zebra.speak())
```

Comment: thank you. But of course using class

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple delegation -

```js
class Zebra {
  constructor(animal) {
    this.Animal = animal; // animal = Animal
  }

  speak() {
    return this.Animal.speak();
  }
}
```

You can also just use functions instead of new classes -

```js
class Zebra {
  constructor(speakFunctionality) {
    this.speak = speakFunctionality;
  }
}

let zebra = new Zebra((name,age) => {  return `my name is: ${this.name} and I am ${this.age} old`; });
zebra.speak();
```

---

The first approach doesn't use composition in the best possible way - because when you want to reimplement or add another implementation you'll need to inherit Animal class or provide a type with `speak()` method.
When doing something like this ask yourself "How do I add a new behavior" - Like you need to implement a `Duck` how would you do it.

The second approach (With functions) is better because you don't need to provide new `class`es but create functions - which are easier to manipulate in JS.

This is usually called `Strategy pattern` where you inject a behavior through  ctor or a function.

The example you provided , where you reimplement "Speak" is best suited for `Inheritance` rather than `Composition`.

---

A good example for composition would be a `Car` with `Engine` and different parts like `Wheels`.

```js
class Car {
  constructor(engine){
    this.Engine = engine;
  }
}
```

Comment: Though you can't use an arrow function in your second example as it has no `this`

Comment: Thank you. But where is the Animal class?

Comment: @pilchard correct, I just copied his example.

mightycodeNewton like the Animal class you have shown in your post